# Finding circles in a live video feed using python 2.7.11and opencv 3.0.0

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I need help finding circles in a live video feed from my webcam. I just need feedback from python that a circle has or has not been detected. Also what is the best method for finding the size of the circle in pixels for better detection.  My code so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()


    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
    cimg = frame.copy()
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, np.array([]), 200, 100, 100, 200)
    if circles == 1:
        print('Circle true')
    else:
        print('No circle')
    cv2.imshow('video',gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So what are you asking? What's not working? Also, please provide example images.

Comment: I want to be able to find any size circle (within reason) in a video stream and then receive confirmation that a circle has or has not been detected. So if I move a disc like object under the webcam then I get a confirmation that a circle has been detected. I believe right now my problem is my circles function.

Answer (score 0):

There it is !

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)
    cirles=cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10)# ret=[[Xpos,Ypos,Radius],...]
    if cirles!=None:print "Circle There !"
    cv2.imshow('video',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:# esc Key
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am new to this site and don't know how to put my code in the grey box. Do you know why my houghcircles would work with 7 parameters? Also say you had a circular object that had a portion of it cut off would there be anyway of making the Houghcircles more sensitive and not to detect it? I have just been playing around with values.


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 60, 1, 200, 70, 70, 80)